# Pull array from table back into controller to create or update new array

Tags: java, html, arrays, jsp, el

So I have a table generated using EL that is requested from a Java class

```html
<table id="medTable" class="goldTable">
<thead>
<tr id="titles">
    <td>Resident SSN</td>
    <td>Medication ID</td>
    <td>Quantity Received</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<c:forEach var="item" items="${allMeds}">
  <tr> 
    <td <!--onclick="listenForDoubleClick(this);" onblur="this.contentEditable=false;"-->${item.resSSN}</td>
    <td <!--onclick="listenForDoubleClick(this);" onblur="this.contentEditable=false;"-->${item.medID}</td>
    <td onclick="listenForDoubleClick(this);" onblur="this.contentEditable=false;">${item.quantity}</td>
  </tr> 
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

The problem, as you can see is the quantity of this table is editable for correction purposes. Now the issue is I don't know how to receive this new information inside my controller to create a new, updated array...This is what my controller looks like for the "update" action...

```html
} else if (request.getParameter("update") != null) {                   
    String[] residentSSN = request.getParameterValues("resSSN");
    //pull from html into multiple arrays
    //push back to html, but content uneditable
    String[] medicationID = request.getParameterValues("medID");
    String[] quantity = request.getParameterValues("quantity");
    //int quantityNum = Integer.parseInt(quantity);
    //allMeds = new ArrayList<OrderedMeds>(residentSSN, medicationID, quantityNum);*/

    url = "/ReceiveMeds.jsp";
}
```

This is what I've tried and clearly it doesn't work. Please help!